# Как использовать moveTo для Actor?

Tags: libgdx

как правильно использовать moveTo?

пытаюсь делать так, но актер не двигается

```
public class MyActions extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private Stage stage;
    private Actor actor;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        stage = new Stage();
        actor = new Actor(){
            {
                setSize(100, 100);
            }
            Sprite actorSprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg")), 57, 10, (int)getWidth(), (int)getHeight());

            @Override
            public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
                actorSprite.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
            }
        };

        stage.addActor(actor);
        actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(500, 500, 1));
    }


    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        actor.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        //stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

поделитесь работающим примером

Comment: А почему stage.act(); закомментировано?

Comment: @Konstantin, пробовал по разному, и с ним тоже, не двигается

Comment: Понятно что не двигается. Вы же нигде не меняете позицию спрайта. Переопределите метод void positionChanged примерно так: actorSprite.setPosition(x, y);

Comment: @MasterFlomaster, заработало, огромное спасибо!